# get active directory container objects for new user

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I want to create a tree of container objects in an active directory domain that a new user can be added to. I can recurse through the domain and get everything within the directory, but I want to limit my scope to ONLY containers that are valid for users.

What would an LDAP query look like to grab the children of a node that were suitable for a user object? Is there a better way to do this?

I'm using c#, System.DirectoryServices, and .net 3.5 if you are curious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the excellent [MSDN article Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) on how to use the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` in .NET 3.5, if you haven't already.

In order to bind to your container, you need to know it's LDAP path and with this, you can establish a context based on that container:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = 
    new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Fabrikam",
                         "ou=TechWriters,dc=fabrikam,dc=com");
```

With this context, you can now e.g. search for certain types of principals in that context:

```
// create a principal object representation to describe
// what will be searched 
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

// define the properties of the search (this can use wildcards)
user.Enabled = false;
user.Name = "user*";

// create a principal searcher for running a search operation
PrincipalSearcher pS = new PrincipalSearcher();

// assign the query filter property for the principal object you created
// you can also pass the user principal in the 
// PrincipalSearcher constructor
pS.QueryFilter = user;

// run the query
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = pS.FindAll();

Console.WriteLine("Disabled accounts starting with a name of 'user':");
foreach (Principal result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("name: {0}", result.Name);
}
```

Does that work for you? Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want to know is what kind of objects in Active Directory can contain *User* object.

I think you can get the answer from the AD schema partition.  I had a quick check on my schema partition which is running Windows 2003 AD.  The *User* object is allowed to be assigned to *OU*, *container*, *builtinDomain* and *domainDNS*.

I didn't check Windows 2008 but I believe it should be the same.  Many people know what *OU* and *container* are.  Few people know what *builtinDomain* and *domainDNS* are.  I doubt if it's useful in your case.  *builtinDomain* is a special container used to contain the built-in account.  By default, AD created a *builtinDomain* at `CN=Builtin,DC=yourdomain,DC=com`.  *domainDNS* is your root domain path `DC=yourdomain,DC=com`.

Here is a function to find all kinds of objects in Active Directory under a particular *node*.  If you think *builtinDomain* and *domainDNS* is not meaningful in your case, just take it out from the LDAP filter.

```
IEnumerable<DirectoryEntry> FindUserParentObject(DirectoryEntry root)
{
    using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root))
    {
        searcher.Filter = "(|(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(objectClass=container)(objectClass=builtinDomain)(objectClass=domainDNS))";
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.PageSize = 1000;
        foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            yield return result.GetDirectoryEntry();
        }
    }
}
```